# Android multi window launcher sidebar

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, sidebar, slidingdrawer

I want this drawerLayout(bellow photo) to always open like Samsung multiwindow sidebar.

Till now I am able to open this drawerLayout(sidebar) within the app.  please give the instruction to be able to open this draweLayout(sidebar) from anywhere(I mean from any other app or even from home screen of a device).

Thanks in advance.

[image: This this the sidebar]

Here is my drayerLayout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Swipe Right"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#D50000"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open App In\nMultiWIndow Mode"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            tools:context=".MainActivity2">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved by making something global you to do some modification in every activity

you can create a new class that will have a method to initialize the navigation, move navigation view to separate xml file and include that file in every activity, and call initialization method in every activity

You can try this library https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer to move most xml code to java so you won't have to add DrawerLayout in every activity but choice is your, it always better to skip using 3rd party libraries if you can

if you are using library than here's some example you can follow

Constant.java

```
private void setupNavigationDrawer() {
    ProfileDrawerItem section = new ProfileDrawerItem()
            .withSetSelected(false)
            .withSetSelected(false)
            .withEnabled(false);
    PrimaryDrawerItem joyType0DrawerItem = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Basic Gamepad").withTag(KEY_BASIC_GAMEPAD_1).withLevel(2);
    PrimaryDrawerItem joyType1DrawerItem = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Assault Horizon").withTag(KEY_ASSAULT_HORIZON).withLevel(2);
    PrimaryDrawerItem joyType2DrawerItem = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Awesomenauts").withTag(KEY_AWESOMENAUTS).withLevel(2);
    PrimaryDrawerItem joyType3DrawerItem = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("BombSquad").withTag(KEY_BOMBSQUAD).withLevel(2);
    PrimaryDrawerItem joyType4DrawerItem = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Final Fantasy XIII").withTag(KEY_FINAL_FANTASY_XIII).withLevel(2);
    SectionDrawerItem sectionDrawerItem = new SectionDrawerItem().withName("Joystick Type").withTextColorRes(R.color.colorAccent);
    PrimaryDrawerItem deviceDrawerItem = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Device Connection").withTag(KEY_DEVICE_CONNECTION).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_devices);
    PrimaryDrawerItem settingsDrawerItem = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Settings").withTag("settings").withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_settings);

    ndMenu = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(tbMain)
            .withCloseOnClick(true)
            .withFireOnInitialOnClick(true)
            .withSelectedItemByPosition(6)
            .withDelayDrawerClickEvent(300)
            .withDisplayBelowStatusBar(true)
            .withTranslucentStatusBar(false)
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(this)
            .addDrawerItems(section, deviceDrawerItem, settingsDrawerItem, sectionDrawerItem, joyType0DrawerItem, joyType1DrawerItem, joyType2DrawerItem, joyType3DrawerItem, joyType4DrawerItem)
            .build();

    findViewById(R.id.nav_button).setOnClickListener(new 
     View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
        // Check these functions from library example to check drawer state and open close drawer
        if(ndMenu.isDrawerOpen){
           ndMenu.closeDrawer();
         } else {
           ndMenu.openDrawer();
         }
        });
}
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
      layout="@layout/nav_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


<LinearLayout>
```

nav_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    orientation="horizontal">

    <Image
      id="@+id/nav_button"
      android:layout_width="30dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"/>


<LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But I'm talking about a sidebar like Samsung multiwindow taskbar. where whenever a user makes the setting on then he can access the sidebar from any app or home screen of a device.